# Showing Leaflet Tile Images inside another div using jquery

Tags: jquery, leaflet

I have a leaflet map which displays an aerial view like this:

```
 var EPSLayer = L.esri.imageMapLayer("https://imagery.gist.in/arcgis/rest/services/Imagery/BestAvailable/ImageServer", {
        opacity: 0.5,
        useCors: false
    });
```

Users click on the map and a popup opens where users type in some data. I need to show the clicked map image on this popup as well.

I have added a div with this code:

```
<div id="dvminMap" style=" position: absolute;right: 0px;" >Minimap <img src=''/></div>
```

And the below script:

```
$('#map').on('click', function(){
    var src = $(this).children('img').attr('src');  
    $('#dvminMap').children('img').attr('src', src);
});
```

This works if Map was a div with an img file inside it, however it fails in this scenario.

Is there a way I could do this ? Or maybe just show whatever was under the mouse during click in the new div ?

Any input or pointers is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused, i'm assuming you want to show all the currently visible maptiles in a popup? That popup would be bigger than the entire map?! Or just the tile image that was clicked on? Please elaborate.

Comment: @iH8 I am only interested in showing a static image. The tile that was clicked on.